# Parity signer new-token unable to parity on the CLI

Tags: wallets, parity, cli

I had issues during the install and re installed the account. 
It is asking for parity signer new-token that clearly needs to be entered o the command line.
This is installed on OSX, I can see the .parity folder but nothing of note in there. If I run a command such as `parity -h` (help) or any variation it is clearly not installed. Where is the CLI command run from?

Comment: Would you mind posting the commands put and errors received?

Answer (score 1):

If you installed Parity via Mac-Installer, the executable is not in your default $PATH of your terminal emulator. You can, however, access it directly by executing:

```
/Applications/Parity\ Ethereum.app/Contents/MacOS/parity --help
```

To generate a new signer token, type:

```
/Applications/Parity\ Ethereum.app/Contents/MacOS/parity signer new-token
```

*Disclosure, I work for Parity.*

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have located the folder and the only file present is the go.sh file. That only points to the local server at port :8080. If I run the app from the link on launchpad it takes me to the web portal where I can see accounts details in the background greyed out with the splash screen for new signer key. I have had look in specific users but is is not in there either? Any other thoughts? Where are the keys kept? Is it worth a complete reinstall? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How did you install parity?  From source or some sort of binary installer?

> Where are the keys kept?

The keys may be in ~/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/keys

They may also be in ~/.parity/keys

The difference is annoying but seems to be the result of building from source vs. installing from binary.

The binary is very likely in ~/parity/target/release/parity if you complied from source.  If you install from a .deb file it's in /usr/bin/parity.  Of course on OSX you don't install from deb file so I don't know.

Have you tried typing

```
$ which parity
```

Or how about:

```
$ find / -name 'parity'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you used the one-line installer to install Parity on Mac OS, your terminal won't know the path to where Parity is installed. Simple way to solve this is by appending an alias under your `~/.bash_profile` file by running the following command:

```
echo "alias parity='/Applications/Parity\ Ethereum.app/Contents/MacOS/parity'" >> ~/.bash_profile && source ~/.bash_profile
```

You can now run parity from your CLI:

```
parity ui
```